# How can a phase be thermodynamically stable at room temperature if it only appears at high temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, stability, phase

How can a phase that appears at high temperature be thermodynamically stable at room temperature? For example, $\alpha$-alumina is a phase that is formed at temperatures above $1000^\circ C$. How is the same phase stable at room temperature?

Comment: If it is a high temperature phase then it isn't thermodynamically stable- the kinetics of transformation are very very slow for solid to solid transformations at low temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$-alumina is thermodynamically stable at room temperature, and also at high temperature (around $1,200-1,400 \space ^{\circ}C$) - however, alpha alumina is not what is typically formed when alumina is made from the various aluminum ores ([ref](http://ref.scielo.org/qprp3k)). Typically, one of the several other crystal structures will form, with different particle sizes and amounts of water (hydration). These and all other phases that are found along the way to $\alpha$-alumina are called **transition aluminas**.

This [link](http://alteo-alumina.com/en/transition-aluminas) explains what happens upon heating. In general, first the crystal is dehydrated, which causes it to form a different, dehydrated phase. Then, as the temperature continues to rise, the alumina crystal structure rearranges into more compact structures, until eventually, near the [sintering point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintering), the atoms have sufficient kinetic energy that they can "find" the most thermodynamically stable configuration - $\alpha$-alumina.

In other words, the transition alumina phases are kinetically trapped in structures that are *not* the most thermodynamically stable, but heating allows them to get out of that trap and into the most favorable state.

Answer (score 0):

As far I have read- alpha-Alumina is stable at room temperature. They just sinter alumina powder at 1000C so the mostly physical reaction happens quickly.